# Sed Process Substitution on Insert - Without Backslashes

Tags: sed

I have function that prints a header that needs to be applied across several files, but if I utilize a sed process substitution the lines prior to the last have a backslash \ on them.

E.g.

```
function print_header() { 
cat << EOF
-------------------------------------------------------------------
$(date '+%B %d, %Y @ ~ %r')  ID:$(echo $RANDOM)
EOF
}
```

If I then take a file such as `test.txt`:
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5

`sed "1 i $(print_header | sed 's/$/\\/g')" test.txt`

I get:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------\
November 24, 2015 @ ~ 11:18:28 AM  ID:13187
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
```

Notice the troublesome backslash at the end of the first line, I'd like to not have that backslash appear. Any ideas?

Comment: `$` is the end of line marker. `s/$/\\/` replaces it by a \. What do you expect? What is the problem?

Comment: @hek2mgl The reason for the them is because the `sed` insert command  seems to need to be backslashed onto seperate lines. Sed eats the last backslash up but leaves any subsequent backslashes in the text.

Comment: Ah, got it. Anyway, I suggest to use `cat` for that. Added an answer.

Comment: @ hek2mgl Thanks anyway, I've got it working a little better this time with a space on the last line yet no backslashes on subsquent lines with: `sed "1 i $(print_header | sed 's/$/\\/g;') " test.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my kludgy fix, if you can find something more elegant I'll gladly credit you:

`sed "1 i $(print_header | sed 's/$/\\/g;$s/$/\x01/')" test.txt | tr -d '\001'`

This puts an unprintable SOH (\x01) ascii Start Of Header character after the inserted text, that precludes the backslashes and then I run it over `tr` to delete the SOH chars.

Answer (score 0):

I would use cat for that:

```
cat <(print_header) file > file_with_header
```

Comment: Thanks I realize there are other ways to get it done. But I specifically want to know how to do this with `sed`, it can be useful to insert blocks of text wherever you want in the text not only at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior depends on the `sed` dialect.  Unfortunately, it's one of the things which depends on which version you have.

To simplify debugging, try specifying verbatim text.  Here's one from a Debian system.

```
vnix$ sed '1i\
> foo\
> bar' <<':'
> hello
> goodbye
> :
foo
bar
hello
goodbye
```

Your diagnostics appear to indicate that your `sed` dialect does not in fact require the backslash after the first `i`.

Since you are generating the contents of the header programmatically anyway, my recommended solution would be to refactor the code so that you can avoid this conundrum.  If you don't want `cat <<EOF test.txt` then maybe experiment with `sed 1r/dev/stdin' <<EOF test.txt` (I could not get `1r-` to work, but `/dev/stdin` should be portable to any Linux.)

Comment: Thanks for the idea `echo -en "$(print_header)" | sed 1r /dev/stdin test.txt` seems to get the job done. Although its not much less kludgy than what I ended up with.

Comment: The `echo` seems completely superfluous; try just `print_header | sed`

Comment: Yea, it works without echo but since its a replace we can't actually address the first line with `sed`. I wish. Looks like I'm stuck with my kludgy insert until someone gives `sed` a new line zero address capability. I've incorporated your idea on my blog since its somewhat clean addresses beyond line 0: http://scriptsandoneliners.blogspot.com/2015/11/sed-inserts-via-process-substitution.html

Comment: Another way to cat to the front using sed: `sed : <(print_header) test.txt` http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/156915-using-sed-insert-text-file-first-line.html